# How to use disaster recovery feature for Azure Service Bus Premium

Tags: azure, service, bus, disaster-recovery

As per our project architecture, we deployed our component in 2 regions. One region is always active, where another is passive. If active regions fails, we divert all traffic to another region using traffic manager. There is one consumer who reads messages from Region 1. 
If region 1 fails, We want to handle disaster recovery from our side without changing anything  at receiver side.

I am currently using azure Service bus standard version. As per documentation Premium version has feature of Disaster Recovery option.

So any idea whether we need manually fail over service bus, or service bus take care about DR.

I am bit confused how DR will work in premium.

Answer (score 0):

According to their architecture : [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/resiliency/disaster-recovery-azure-applications)

this is an automated process 
where the VM :

> automatically creates the required resources in the target region,
>   based on the source VM settings.
>   It provides automated continuous replication, and enables you to
>   perform application failover with a single click. You can also run
>   disaster recovery drills by testing failover, without affecting your
>   production workloads or ongoing replication.

so i guess to answer your question it is an automated process

ref
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/resiliency/disaster-recovery-azure-applications) for further info on architecture and indepth on how it works

for Git source on samples : [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/GeoDR/SBGeoDR2/)

Comment: Whether In Premium version, service bus never goes down, and it is always available 100%?
Or there are chances of outage/down of service bus in premium as well? 

Not much details found on availability
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr